# How would I solve these types of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Going back to college and been a few years since I've had to do any algebra/trig.
How would I go about solving these types of equations and do they have a name?

> a(y-b)=by+c then, except when the denominator is zero y=

On a side note can anyone comment on any resources for reviewing algebra,trig,pre-calc? 
I have to take a placement test and would rather not have to retake my lower math courses...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

$$a(y-b)=by+c$$

So:

$$ay-ab=by+c$$

Putting all the terms with $y$ in the same side:

$$ay-by=ab+c$$
$$(a-b)y=ab+c$$

So, if $a \neq b$:

$$y = \frac{ab+c}{a-b}$$

To review some stuff you can take a look here: https://www.khanacademy.org/ The videos are short, everything is well explained and you can choose the specific topic you need.